# React - saved value always reads as NULL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component which has been passed a `parameter` in its route from another component. I save the `value` in a cost in order to use it.

```
  const params = useParams()
const id = params.id;
```

if I click on the `Card component` it would navigate me to a different route which has the component `card details`

when using `console.log(id)` I get the proper value.

now I have this array of objects from back-end and there is where I need the `ID` parameter for compare.

```
const [state, setState] = useState<any>(store.getState().perfumeState.perfumes);
```

Here is the array of `perfumes` which is stored in store of `redux`

So basically What I am trying to do is find the specific `perfume` object with the given `ID` and for that I used:

```
 var result = state.filter(obj => {
        return obj.id === id // <------- Returns `NULL` // return obj.id === 2 // <-------- Returns correct value
      })
```

here I have an issue. while I hard-code a number I get the proper result, however, when I use the `id` value it returns `null`.
also, Instead of getting an object I get an `array` of `one` object each time.

Comment: you can use `.find` instead of `.filter` to get the first result. The other problem could be solved when u use `useEffect` with `id` as dependecy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route parameters from `useParams` always have `string` values (or are `undefined`). So if the `id` field on your objects has type `number`, then equality checks with [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (`===`) will never pass.

You can fix this by using either the [normal equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (`==`) or by casting `id` (from `params`) to a `number`.

Either:

```
const result = state.filter(obj => obj.id == id);
```

or:

```
const result = state.filter(obj => obj.id === Number(id));
```

Would recommend casting to a number and keeping strict equality (especially since your eslint settings will probably warn you about using the normal equality operator).

---

As for getting a single object rather than an array, you can use the [`find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (instead of `filter`), which will return the first element satisfying your condition or `undefined`. Like this:

```
const result = state.find(obj => obj.id === Number(id));
```

Comment: That did the trick. I knew I was in the right way. was just a matter of syntax and a small change. thanks